# Django Form (Checkbox) - unable to save data

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views, django-widget

I am trying to display a form (with multiple select checkbox) and save the data in database. But having some problem.

Here is my model:

```
class Preference(models.Model):

    CLASS_CHOICES = [('1', '1'), ('2', '2'), ('3', '3')]
    BOARD_CHOICES = [('C', 'CBSE'), ('I', 'ICSE'), ('S', 'State Board')]
    SUBJECT_CHOICES = [('H', 'HINDI'), ('M', 'MATH'), ('E', 'ENGLISH')]

    class = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=CLASS_CHOICES, default='1', blank=False)
    board = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=BOARD_CHOICES, default='C', blank=False)
    subject = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=SUBJECT_CHOICES, default='M', blank=False)
```

My form:

```
class PreferenceForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Preference
        fields = ['class', 'board', 'subject']
        widgets = {
            'board': forms.RadioSelect(),
            'subject': forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple()
        }
```

My view:

```
def pref(request):
    form = PreferenceForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return render(request, 'website/thanks.html')
    else:
        print(form.errors)
        return render(request, 'website/pref.html', {'form': form})
```

It displays the form with checkbox but I am unable to save that data to database even when I select a single choice.

Error Displayed:- `

```
<li>Subject<ul class="errorlist"><li>Select a valid choice. [&#39;H&#39;, &#39;M&#39;] is not one of the available choices.</li></ul></li>
```

All help/suggestions are appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, rename the `class` field inside your model to something else. `class` is a Python reserved word and it might cause you trouble later on.

Secondly, in order to render a `CharField` as a `CheckboxSelectMultiple` widget your model's fields declaration must change. Now, you're telling the `subject` field to accept a single value (amongst the `'H'`, `'M'` and `'E'` values), but, via your form, you try to give it multiplte values (`[&#39;H&#39;, &#39;M&#39;]`, which means `'H'` and `'M'`). That's the cause of your error. It's expecting one value while you give it more than one.

Solution to your problem is to create another model, say `Subject` and inside that model declare the `SUBJECT_CHOICES` and a single field (say `name`). Then in your `Preference` model, change the `subject` field into a [`ManyToManyField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField), instead of a `CharField`. In that way, the `subject` field of the `Preference` model will be able to accept more than one values.

Something like this:

```
class Subject(models.Model):

    HINDI = 'H'
    MATH = 'M'
    ENGLISH = 'E'

    SUBJECT_CHOICES = [
        (HINDI, 'HINDI'),
        (MATH, 'MATH'),
        (ENGLISH, 'ENGLISH')
    ]

    name = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=SUBJECT_CHOICES, default=MATH)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Preference(models.Model):

    CLASS_CHOICES = [('1', '1'), ('2', '2'), ('3', '3')]
    BOARD_CHOICES = [('C', 'CBSE'), ('I', 'ICSE'), ('S', 'State Board')]

    # RENAME THE class FIELD PLEASE, i.e class_number!
    class = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=CLASS_CHOICES, default='1', blank=False)
    board = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=BOARD_CHOICES, default='C', blank=False)
    # Notice the plural name of the field. Subjects, not subject, since we're expecting more than one value into this field.
    subjects = models.ManyToManyField(Subject)
```

Finally:

1. Don't forget to create the `Subject` objects (via the admin or the `./manage shell`). If you use the admin it's fairly simple. If you use the `shell` then do the following:

   ```
   from myapp.models import Subject

   [Subject.objects.create(name=choice[0]) for choice in Subject.SUBJECT_CHOICES]
   ```
2. Update the `forms.py` file with the new field name `subjects`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. By using your method when I display the choices in the form it just displays a single checkbox with label 'Subject object' instead of all the subjects.

Comment: Updated my answer. You have to create the `Subject` objects first and of course put a `__str__` method inside it to print the name instead of the ugly `'Subject object'`.

Comment: Already changed the field name to subjects and created the Subject objects but still not able to display. Can u please guide me about creating Subject objects properly.

Comment: Updated once more.

Comment: Glad I could help. If you like, in order to avoid accidentaly duplicated values of subject (because right now you can enter another value of `H` or `M`, ending up to have multiple values of the same names), you can change the definition of `name` into this: `name = models.CharField(max_length=2, unique=True, choices=SUBJECT_CHOICES, default=MATH)`. Of course, after that run migrations ;)